# I'm trying to open a dll written in c with python ctypes and run the function in it, but it comes as a char, not a string

Tags: python, c, dll, ctypes

These are the codes I am working on:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void test_print(char test[100])
{
        printf("%s", test);
}
```

```py
from ctypes import *
libcdll = CDLL("test.dll")

libcdll.test_print("test")
```

But when i run the program i get "t" instead of "test".

Comment: Try `libcdll.test_print(b"test")` instead

Comment: yep, it work thank you :)

Comment: based on what @n.'pronouns'm. wrote, I assume the following explanation: python `str` objects are unicode strings, with 2 bytes per character. Most systems use little-endian byte order, so `"test"` is internally represented as `b"t\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00"`. The C code then expects a `'\0'`-terminated string and stops after the first `"t"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ALWAYS* set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for your functions to save headache.  `ctypes` can verify the arguments are passed correctly.

Example:

test.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

__declspec(dllexport)        // required for exporting a function on Windows
void test_print(char* test)  // decays to pointer, so char test[100] is misleading.
{
        printf("%s", test);
}
```

test.py

```py
from ctypes import *
libcdll = CDLL("./test")
libcdll.test_print.argtypes = c_char_p,  # for (char*) arguments, comma makes a tuple
libcdll.test_print.restype = None       # for void return
libcdll.test_print(b"test")
```

output:

```
test
```

If called with "test" as in the OP question, now it will tell you the parameter is wrong:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    libcdll.test_print("test")
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Without `.argtypes`, `ctypes` defaults to converting "test" from a Python `str` to a `wchar_t*` encoded as UTF-16LE on Windows, so  it would look like the following, and `printf` will stop at the first null byte (`\x00`), explaining `t` as the output.

```py
>>> 'test'.encode('utf-16le')
b't\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00'
```

Note that if you want to pass Python `str` instead of `bytes`, declare the C function as the following and use `.argtypes = c_wchar_p,` instead:

```c
void test_print(wchar_t* test) {
        wprintf(L"%s", test);  // wide version of printf and format string
}
```

Comment: So if I were using a defined variable instead of a sentence, should I type libcdll.test_print(b(variable))?

Comment: @SteryNomo No, `b'xxxx'` is only the syntax to generate a byte string literal.  Assign the variable a byte string, e.g. `v = b'hello'`, or if you have a Unicode string (type `str`) you can convert it by encoding it to a byte string, e.g. `v = "hello"; test_print(v.encode())`.  The default encoding is `utf-8`.

Comment: thank you very much if you didn't see my question i would never finished my project :)