# Problem calling C++ DLL from Python using ctypes

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I'm linking python code to an existing C++ library. I'm creating a DLL to call the library which I load in python with ctypes. The functions which take strings have to have the string defined as a b"..." not as a regular string. I notice the examples in the ctypes documentation all do that. Why? What's the difference? Is there ever a situation where I can call with a regular string?

Example:

```
import ctypes
nifly_path = r"D:/OneDrive/Dev/NiflyDLL/NiflyDLL/x64/Debug/NiflyDLL.dll"
test_file = r"D:/OneDrive/Dev/PyNifly/PyNifly/tests/test.nif"
nifly = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(nifly_path)
nifly.nifLoadShapeNames.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int]
buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(50)

print(nifly.getVersion())

buf = ctypes.create_string_buffer(50)
print('Call as byte array')
print(nifly.nifLoadShapeNames(test_file.encode('utf-8'), buf, 50))
print(buf.value.decode('utf-8'))
print('Call as string')
print(nifly.nifLoadShapeNames(test_file, buf, 50))
print(buf.value)
```

The first call to nifLoadShapeNames() works, the second fails with , but I don't understand why.

Comment: what NIFLY_API  does expand to? call conventions are important

Comment: Edited the OP with that information.

Comment: I think the problem isn't the pointer, it's passing the filename into the nifLoad() call. Somehow the python string isn't accepted but a string of the form b"..." is. If anyone understands why I'd love to hear it.

Comment: So, you can delete all the rest of the code because it's not part of a [mcve]. In any case, how should Python guess what the first parameter to that function is supposed to be? All it knows is that you pass in a Python string, not how it's to convert or transcode it for the C function.

Comment: By the way: If you have control over the C++ library, there are much better ways to expose a C++ class to Python, like e.g. Boost.Python.

Comment: I'll trim down the example. But I'm still not understanding how to use ctypes, really. I used argtypes to describe the values. Documentation says python types *except* integers, strings, and bytes objects have to be wrapped--so strings should be okay, right? And what's different about b"..." over a regular string that allows it to be passed correctly?

Comment: See [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66909369/235698) as it is the exact same problem.  *ALWAYS* set `.argtypes` and `.restype` for each function wrapped.

Comment: I drastically trimmed down the question now that I know better what's going on, but I'm still not understanding what the difference is that makes the b".." string work. I'll look into Boost.Python.

Comment: It's different format, essentially `b""` is zero-terminated string of `char` and default one is one of `wchar_t`. If you try interpret latter as former, you get only first character and it would stop at zero byte.

Comment: ***light dawns***

Comment: With `.argtypes` set properly to `c_char_p`, the 2nd one would fail with "wrong type" if passed `"file"` vs. `b"file"`.  The answer I linked explains why.  Did you read it?

Comment: Yes, of course, but you underestimate the depths of my ignorance. I didn't realize a regular string was a string of wchars, not bytes.

Comment: The last half of my answer in that questions describes `ctypes` converting Python `str` to `wchar_t*` with an example, but if it isn't clear let me know why and I'll try to improve it.  This type of problem is very common with ctypes new users.